# How to know with whom my page has been shared

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins

I'd like to create a Facebook/Twitter application and use Facebook's social plugins/Twitter API to let people share my pages on Facebook or Tweet about it.

Is there any way that I can find out with whom the users shared my page in Twitter/Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the shares are done using your own app, and you log the publishes, there's no way to know

Comment: Suppose all shares are done using my app. Would I be able to know exatcly who saw the share?

Comment: Who saw it, no, only who posted it and where they posted it to, you could also use the API to retrieve the likes and comments on it